# How to use mutate for a new column based the data in multiple existing columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Good Morning,

this is my data set containing data of different client's races.

```
White  Asian  Black  Native  Islander  Other
1       0       0      0       0         0
0       1       0      0       0         0
0       0       0      1       0         0
0       0       1      0       0         0
1       0       0      0       1         0
0       0       0      0       0         1
```

The data is stored with a Boolean where 0 = No and 1 = Yes

So if a client has 1 for the column white, then they are white.

But if a client has a 1 for white and islander then they are multi racial.

So this would be my desired output

```
White  Asian  Black  Native  Islander  Other   Race
1       0       0      0       0         0     White
0       1       0      0       0         0     Asian
0       0       0      1       0         0     Native
0       0       1      0       0         0     Black
1       0       0      0       1         0     Multi-Racial 
0       0       0      0       0         1     Other
```

I'm familiar with mutate() but I've only used mutate based off one column.

Can anyone provide a code that can help with my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ifelse()` with `max.col()` should get you what you want. For rows that only have one value you index the name the value was in, otherwise it is `"Multi-Racial"`

```
df1$Race <- ifelse(rowSums(df1) == 1, names(df1)[max.col(df1)], "Multi-Racial")
df1
  White Asian Black Native Islander Other         Race
1     1     0     0      0        0     0        White
2     0     1     0      0        0     0        Asian
3     0     0     0      1        0     0       Native
4     0     0     1      0        0     0        Black
5     1     0     0      0        1     0 Multi-Racial
6     0     0     0      0        0     1        Other
```

Or, using `mutate()`:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(Race = ifelse(rowSums(.) == 1, names(.)[max.col(.)], "Multi-Racial"))
```

**Data**:

```
df1 <- read.table(header = T, text = "White  Asian  Black  Native  Islander  Other
1       0       0      0       0         0
0       1       0      0       0         0
0       0       0      1       0         0
0       0       1      0       0         0
1       0       0      0       1         0
0       0       0      0       0         1")
```

Comment: Hello Andrew, What do i do if the rowsum() is equals 0? Can i have the ouput be unknown instead of "Multi-Racial"?

Comment: You can indeed! You can either nest another `ifelse()` statement, use `dplyr::case_when()`. I would use `dplyr::case_when()` and can post an example if you cannot crack if after looking at some of the [examples](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html)

Comment: Hey thank you Andrew, I ended up using mutate(Rowsum = Rowsum(df1)) and then did another mutate case_when that signaled if Rowsum >=1 ~ '0', and if RowSum = 0 ~ '1'. Then I renamed the column to "Unknown", because if the value in there was 1, then race was unknown. Now I had a column for White, Asian, Black, Native, Islander, Other, and Unknown. I then ran the original code you gave me and it worked. Took me a long time to come up with that but thank you for helping me.